# Laravel: Unique foreign key per another foreign key (user_id)

Tags: laravel, model

I have a UserCategoryFollows table which has a `user_id` related to Users and a `category_id` related to Categories.

Users can follow any amount of Categories, but I don't want to insert multiple rows for the same `category_id` and `user_id`.

For example, I don't want this in my database:

```
user_id     category_id
1           2
2           1
2           3
1           4
2           1   <---- Duplicate
1           2   <---- Duplicate
```

Is this something I can validate inside the Model or is this validation done via controllers?

I'm currently seeding:

```
public function run()
    {

        $catCount = App\Category::count();
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        $follows = [];

        for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
            $user_id = App\User::all()->random()->id;
            $category_id = $faker->numberBetween(1, $catCount);

            $follow = [
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'category_id' => $category_id
            ];


                array_push($follows, $follow);



        }



        foreach ($follows as $follow) {
            App\UserCategoryFollow::create($follow);
        }

    }
```

I could alter my array to pluck out duplicates, but I think it would be better to handle on the model if possible.

Comment: what is the relation between user and category? How many category a user can belongs to ?

Comment: Also I would like to see the migration files of your tables.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu sorry, I just returned and was able to get it answered by someone else

Comment: By the way, if you will be having unique combination of category and user, why just not put category_id as foreign key in users table, why you need an additional table for that.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, the categories relates to Posts (Threads). I suppose I could have named the table better. Basically, users can follow any number of Post Categories like you would on reddit

Comment: in that case you need a pivot table.

Comment: I will look into that. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, you want to add this line to your **migration file** *(this step is **optional** but it is better to implement it to ensure data integrity)*

```
$table->unique(['user_id', 'category_id']);
```

Secondly, use **firstOrCreate** based on your user_id and category id to automatically avoid inserting non-unique values

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
        $user_id = App\User::all()->random()->id;
        $category_id = $faker->numberBetween(1, $catCount);
        App\UserCategoryFollow::firstOrCreate( ['user_id' => $user_id,'category_id' => $category_id]);
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: I did notice an integrity constraint violation on some seeds. Is firstOrCreate() supposed to ignore duplicates?

Comment: This probably you have an already non-unique records in your table you probably need to remove it out manually before migration, although firstOrCreate does not need the first step to be done in order for it to work, you can use it directly

Comment: This is after emptying the table and running `php artisan migrate:refresh -seed`. Sometimes it'll happen, other times it will run correctly. No matter - I'll figure it out. thanks!

Comment: The issue was I had a factory class that was interfering